# Site rendering differently with and without "www"

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, node.js

I recently developed a site, and was surprised to find that the section labeled "Transparent Pricing" shows different prices when I access the site with or without the "www."

`nmbs.io` displays the correct pricing.

While `www.nmbs.io` shows the old/incorrect pricing.

This leads me to believe that somehow the code is different between these two, even though they point to the same IP on my DNS – could this be a caching issue?

Any ideas what is happening here and how to resolve it?

*A few notes to make this more specific*

• The site is build in Node 6.0.0

• I am using Cloudflare

• I don't believe there's any sort of special server-side caching going on

Comment: What tech are you using to host the site?  Wordpress?
Both sites have the same pricing for me so could be caching

Comment: I see $199 at nmbs.io & $166 at www.nmbs.io.

Comment: That said, you're question is much too broad for us to answer and will likely be close as off topic. There are dozens of possibilities.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski Yes, that's what I'm seeing as well. The site is built in Node 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad question, but here's a list of possibilities:

- the IPs can be different
- the IPs can have been different in the past and the caching may not have expired
- the server may react differently, depending on its configuration.
- server-side caching
- server-side reverse proxy caching
- Cloudflare caching or some other protection system
- client-side proxy caching
- client-side caching

You had already examined the first two possibilities. The fact that there was no problem for other people points to caching on your side.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turned out that Cloudflare was caching, so once I switched that off all of the changes looked good. It also explains why Stefan saw the same issue I did — we're both based in the Bay Area.

Comment: Didn't check for Cloudflare :) Edited answer to include that!